# Time required to create an FFTW plan in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fftw

I noticed that the time used to create an FFTW plan in Fortran using `dfftw_plan_dft_1d` is extremely long compared to C++ when the length of the data is in the order of 2^20. What is the reason for this?

-----------EDIT------------

The issue is resolved now. I was using `fftw_measure` in fortran but `fftw_estimate` in c++. By changing to `fftw_estimate` fortran is now much faster.

Comment: It depends on which method you use - `FFTW_ESTIMATE` is quite fast, but `FFTW_MEASURE` can be very slow.

Comment: I use `fftw_estimate`.

Comment: Sorry I was indeed using `fftw_measure` in fortran but `fftw_estimate` in c++. By changing to `fftw_estimate` it is now much faster.

Comment: Indeed, according to [the documentation of FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html), as the flag `FFTW_MEASURE` is used, many FFT are actually computed to choose the fastest algorithm. If the plan is used only a couple of times, it is better to used the flag `FFTW_ESTIMATE`. In this case, the input array is not modified as the plan is created and a suitable algorithm is chosen.